# How to ignore pyparsing ParseException and proceed?

Tags: python, text-processing, pyparsing

I would like to ignore the line in a file which does not match with all predefined parser and proceed. The line(s) that I would like to ignore is in wide range which I couldn't inspect and define parser for each of them.

I use try..except with pass once ParseException is caught. However, the parsing stops immediately.

```
try:
    return parser.parseFile(filename, parse_all)

except ParseException, err:
    msg = 'Error during parsing of {}, line {}'.format(filename, err.lineno)
    msg += '\n' + '-'*70 + '\n'
    msg += err.line + '\n'
    msg += ' '*(err.col-1) + '^\n'
    msg += '-'*70 + '\n' + err.msg
    err.msg = msg

    print(err.msg)
    pass
```

I would like to proceed even if there is a ParseException.

Comment: What do you mean by `the parsing stops immediately.`? Do you mean your program exits cleanly? Or is there another exception raised? If the latter, please post the new Traceback.

Comment: Also a small nitpick: You don't need `pass` at the end of your except-block.

Comment: @That1Guy I would like to proceed the file parsing instead of just exit gracefully with the exception error.

Comment: I'm asking for clarification - *what do you mean* when you say "the parsing stops immediately"? Does it stop because your program exits? Or does it stop *because of another error*? Do you get any output at all? Do you see the string in your print statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyparsing doesn't really have a "continue on error" option, so you'll need to adjust your parser so that it doesn't raise the ParseException in the first place. What you might try is adding to your parser something like `| SkipTo(LineEnd())('errors*')` as a last-ditch catch-all. Then you could look at the errors results name to see what lines went astray (or add a parse action to that expression to capture more than just the current line).

```
import pyparsing as pp

era = "The" + pp.oneOf("Age Years") + "of" + pp.Word(pp.alphas)

era.runTests("""
    The Age of Enlightenment
    The Years of Darkness
    The Spanish Inquisition
    """)
```

Prints:

```
The Age of Enlightenment
['The', 'Age', 'of', 'Enlightenment']

The Years of Darkness
['The', 'Years', 'of', 'Darkness']

The Spanish Inquisition
    ^
FAIL: Expected Age | Years (at char 4), (line:1, col:5)
```

Add these lines and call runTests again:

```
# added to handle lines that don't match
unexpected = pp.SkipTo(pp.LineEnd(), include=True)("no_one_expects")
era = era | unexpected
```

Prints:

```
The Age of Enlightenment
['The', 'Age', 'of', 'Enlightenment']

The Years of Darkness
['The', 'Years', 'of', 'Darkness']

The Spanish Inquisition
['The Spanish Inquisition']
 - no_one_expects: 'The Spanish Inquisition'
```

Comment: This often happens when the parser has a `ZeroOrMore` or a `OneOrMore(expressions that might match the empty string)` expression that ends up spinning forever. Try adding `setDebug()` on one of your parser expressions, or add some output to a parse action if you have any of these. Beyond that, you may have to post more details.

Comment: Ha! The `SkipTo()` has to parse the `LineEnd()` also, which is does not do by default.  Add `include=True` to get this. Answer edited.

Comment: Also, change `pp.ZeroOrMore(rules)` to `pp.OneOrMore(rules)`. This was a bug in `dictOf` also, and would make the parser spin forever. But you may have to post this as a new question - your code sample is not easy to follow, and SO does not like long discussion threads on a given question.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I've asked the question with more details in a separate thread. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55798690/11395555